# Problem with modal events in an Angular component

Tags: angular, events, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

My problem is this peace of code:

```
    <div class="alert my-5" *ngFor="let alert of alerts; let i = index">
        <div class="alert-container" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal3"
            (click)="onEdit(alert.id!)">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                <div class="box-shadow-services">
                    <div class="checkbox-wrapper-7">
                        <input class="tgl tgl-ios" [id]="'cb2-'+i" type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="alert.isPublished"
                            (change)="onPublishedChange(alert.id!)"
                            (click)="$event.preventDefault(); $event.stopPropagation();togglePublish(alert)" />
                        <label class="tgl-btn" [for]="'cb2-'+i"></label>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="actions-container">
                    <i class="bi bi-x-circle-fill" (click)="$event.stopPropagation(); onDelete(alert.id!)"
                        data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
            <h5 class="mb-3 alert-title fw-bold">{{ alert.title }}</h5>
            <p class="mb-3 alert-message">{{ alert.message }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This looks like this:

[image]

They are alerts. When I click on an alert, a modal is displayed with the alert data so I can edit it.

However, the checkbox in the upper left corner is for publishing or unpublishing an alert, and when I click on said checkbox, the publish/unpublish action is carried out, but the modal appears as if I were clicking on the rest of the alert to view its details.

I need the modal to not be shown when I click on the checkbox.

When I click on the 'x' in the upper right side, it does behave as it should. Skip a different modal to remove the alert. That operation is correct.

The code referring to the checkbox specifically is this:

```
<div class="box-shadow-services">
                        <div class="checkbox-wrapper-7">
                            <input class="tgl tgl-ios" [id]="'cb2-'+i" type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="alert.isPublished"
                                (change)="onPublishedChange(alert.id!)"
                                (click)="$event.preventDefault(); $event.stopPropagation();togglePublish(alert)" />
                            <label class="tgl-btn" [for]="'cb2-'+i"></label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

I think the stopPropagation() there really doesn't do anything.